# How to aggregate/reduce a pytorch tensor, with a custom lambda function, in it's lowest dimension?

Tags: pytorch, aggregate, reduce, tensor

torch let's us easily aggregate the lowest dimension with operators like `torch.max(x, dim=-1)` or `torch.sum(x, dim=-1)`, how would this be done with a function like `t_conorm = lambda u, v: u + v - u * v` (Algebraic t-conorm).

Can this be done with something like `torch.reduce(x, t_conorm, dim=-1)`. But it seems torch does not have such a reduce method. And also can this be done somewhat efficiently (similar to torch.max, torch.sum,...) when the operators used in the lambda function are also only aggregation functions?

for example:

```
a = torch.Tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]])
t_conorm = lambda u, v: u + v - u * v
b = torch.reduce(a, t_conorm, dim=-1)
print(b)
>> torch.Tensor([0.496, 0.664])
```